# How to create a specific helmet that will make the player's speed decreased when worn?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I want to make a set of armor called the "soldier's armor" that each piece will change the wearer's armor and speed attribute. I can see stuff on effects and stuff but nothing on attributes.

Comment: https://minecraft.fandom.com/wiki/Attribute#Applying_attributes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/give @p iron_helmet{display:{Name:'{"text":"soldier\'s armor"}'},AttributeModifiers:[{AttributeName:"generic.movement_speed",Name:"generic.movement_speed",Amount:-1,Operation:2,UUID:[I;1622081779,-228898738,-2128344364,2005408682]}]} 1
```

The following command is a /give command. This command has attributes that change movement speed when worn. It uses a negative amount so it slows the player. You can edit this amount to change speeds.